# Login failed during Azure Release Pipeline DACPAC deployment

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-server, dacpac

I am trying to deploy a dacpac to a database in Azure SQL server using a release pipeline in azure devops. I was able to deploy a dacpac to one database successfully by adding Azure Object Name as db_owner of that database.
I repeated the same step for a different dacpac, but I am getting an error saying the access failed.

```
2022-04-06T21:54:52.4823080Z Initializing deployment (Start)
2022-04-06T21:55:49.0595299Z Initializing deployment (Failed)
2022-04-06T21:55:49.0721494Z Time elapsed 0:00:57.89
2022-04-06T21:55:49.2784337Z ##[error]*** An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue.
2022-04-06T21:55:49.2883974Z ##[error]Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'.
```

using service principal as authentication (using SPN of service connection for the service principal)
DB server : xyz
DB databases : xyz.a  xyz.b

a is successful, but b fails on same release pipeline.

it seems like access token was successfully grabbed in the script.

Answer (score 2):

Some `dacpac` deployments were successful because the `dacpac`s had permissions that were included in the SG which was set as the AAD Admin of the SQL servers.

The `dacpac`s which had permissions which were *not* included in the AAD Admin SG were failing. The solution was to drop the permission objects using the `sqlpackage.exe` flag:

```
/p:ExcludeObjectTypes=Users;ServerRoleMembership;ServerRoles;DatabaseRoles;RoleMembership;Users;Permissions
```